# OpenVPN: per client MTU

Tags: openvpn

I have a somewhat large VPN network which works perfectly with "mtu-test". On one client, the mtu-test fails because of a broken MTU discovery so I have create a special configuration on the server for this client (because "fragment 1300 on the **client only** breaks everything).

I tried my luck with the client file in client-config-dir, but got an error "option 'fragment' cannot be used in this context".

What to do?